# How to create a file with FileOptions.Encrypted in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, encryption

I'm trying to create a file with `FileOptions.Encrypted` using the following code:

```
FileStream fout = File.Create("out.txt", 2 << 12, FileOptions.Encrypted);
```

But I'm getting `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`. I've even tried to create the file in my *Desktop*, but the error persists.

What is the correct way of creating a file with `FileOptions.Encrypted` option?

Comment: `2 << 12` is not 2 to the 12th power. It is the 13th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MSDN document, an UnauthorizedAccessException is thrown when:

```
Encrypted is specified for options and file encryption is not supported on the current platform.
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe that is the problem: My Windows is Home Basic 7.